# "ROUND" calculation can't be lower than 1.0

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, rounding, google-sheets-formula

I need a `ROUND` calculation to always round up when it lands between 0 and 1 (but not when it's a value above these numbers), but can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

This is what I have currently:

```
=ROUND(100/DATA!H6)
```

Comment: The similar ROUNDUP is probably what you want?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF((100/DATA!H6>0)*(100/DATA!H6<1), ROUNDUP(100/DATA!H6, ), 100/DATA!H6)
```

---

[image: 0]

[image: 0]